# Result of function is "garbage" when getting current directory?

Tags: c, working-directory

Why does the following code, produce the following output?

**UPDATING MY CODE TO THIS:
i get basically the same thing.**

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <direct.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir getcwd
#endif

//==============================MAIN=======================================
#ifdef _WIN32   
    int main(int argc, char **argv) 
    {
        char *path = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*FILENAME_MAX);
        GetCurrentDir(path, sizeof(path));
        printf("path: %s\n", path);
        //other stuff
    }

//==============================END========================================
```

**OUTPUT**
path : -

Comment: It's difficult to say, because you haven't posted your **actual** code.  Have you tried stepping through in a debugger?

Comment: This is my actual code, copy pasted right out of my program.

Comment: Ok, I see you've now added the `printf` statement...

Comment: Your size calculation being passed into `GetCurrentDir` is now wrong.  `sizeof(some_pointer)` != `sizeof(some_array)`, even if they point to the same amount of memory. I posted an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable declared in `get_current_path`, i.e., a variable that will likely be cleaned up once the function returns.  You should accept a buffer as an argument and fill it for the caller, i.e.,

```
void char* get_current_path(char* outDir)
```

PER YOUR EDIT:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    char *path = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*FILENAME_MAX);
    GetCurrentDir(path, sizeof(path));
    printf("path: %s\n", path);
    //other stuff
}
```

`sizeof(path)` is going to be 4 or 8 (32-bit or 64-bit) as it is now just a pointer, not an array.  You need to pass in the actual size, i.e., `sizeof(char) * FILENAME_MAX`, so...

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    size_t bufSize = sizeof(char) * FILENAME_MAX;
    char *path = (char*)malloc(bufSize);
    GetCurrentDir(path, bufSize);
    printf("path: %s\n", path);
    //other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`current_dir` is a stack variable, and is getting clobbered upon return.  Either declare it `static` or accept a `char` buffer as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`current_dir` is local to `get_current_path()` so when the function returns it is popped off the stack and the runtime is free to stick whatever it wants into those stack locations. That's why the `printf` prints gibberish.

To fix the problem do one of the following

- declare the array as `static`
- move array declaration to file scope (I'd also make it a `static` array) and then `main()` can refer to to the array directly, no need to pass a pointer back
- use `malloc` to allocate the buffer within the `get_current_path()` function and return the allocated buffer pointer. If you do this, do not forget to `free` the allocated memory once you're done using it.
- as @JonathanPatschke says in his answer, you can also change `get_current_path()` to accept a pointer to the array, then you don't need to make it `static`.